# How do I set up a view/path to an AJAX call in Django?

Tags: ajax, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-urls

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I have this file in my project

```
web/views/tax_calculator.py
```

which consists of a single function (I'm leaving out the imports) ...

```
def calculate_taxes(request):
    state = request.GET.get('state', None)
    gross_income = request.GET.get('gross', None)
    owner_salary = request.GET.get('salary', None)

    data = {
        'sole_pr_taxes': TaxCalculatorService.calc_sole_pr_taxes(state, gross_income),
        's_corp_taxes': TaxCalculatorService.calc_s_corp_taxes(state, gross_income, owner_salary),
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

In my ./myproject/urls.py file I have

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from web.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^ajax/calculate_taxes/$', tax_calculator.calculate_taxes, name='calculate_taxes'),
]
```

but this results in an error

```
    path(r'^ajax/calculate_taxes/$', tax_calculator.calculate_taxes, name='calculate_taxes'),
NameError: name 'tax_calculator' is not defined
```

What's the right way to reference my view/AJAX call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Changing your urls.py code to below code

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from web.views.tax_calculator import calculate_taxes

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^ajax/calculate_taxes/$', calculate_taxes, name='calculate_taxes'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually calculate_taxes would be defined in web/views.py, then it can simply be referred to as calculate_taxes.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `web/views` directory in the `__init__.py` file you have to import `tax_calculator.py` like this:

```py
# __init__.py
from . import tax_calculator
```

If you don’t have the `__init__.py` file you have to create it.